# How to add Callouts to an image using a software installed by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, image-processing, image-editor

What's the easiest way to add Callouts to an image given the capabilities of a default Ubuntu 12.04?

I've got Gimp 2.6 already present (although I am not suggesting it is present in a default Ubuntu) and I find the instructions for adding a Callout via Gimp to be tedious.  There is something called **Gimp Dynamic Text plugin** but I've read that it's very old and so unlikely to work in 2.6 and you probably have to compile C files to get it to work; so it could be messy and still may be a bad cost-benefit prospect.

If the answer does not involve Gimp, that would be welcome.

Comment: Take a look at [GIMP Plugin Registry](http://registry.gimp.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use LibreOffice Draw for adding basic callouts to images and then exporting them in the required format. It's pretty easy and LibreOffice Draw is installed by default on Ubuntu.

Launch LibreOffice Draw using Dash (press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key) and querying for LibreOffice.

[image: launcher]

Insert the picture you wish to add the Callouts to. Navigate through *Insert* Menu → *Picture* → *From File* → browse and locate the picture/image.

[image: insert picture/image]

Make sure that there is a check mark before the Drawing Toolbar. Navigate through *View* → *Toolbars* → *Drawing*.

[image: check for drawing toolbar]

Find the Callouts Button in the Drawing Toolbar. If you cannot find it, then expand the arrow at the right.

[image: Callouts button]

The different Callouts style available are shown in the image below:

[image: Callouts toolbar]

Apply the style you wish and then export as png/jpg/gif/any other format of your choice using *File* Menu → *Export*. Crop and resize the image as necessary.

[image: Sample]